# Programmatically check if shared preference key encrypted

Tags: android, encryption, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to programmatically check if a key stored in shared preference is encrypted?

**Use case:**

I have an **onSharedPreferenceChanged** listener which listens to changes in shared preferences. If there is any change, then it tries to decrypt the shared preference key received in the callback.

Since shared preference files have both encrypted and decrypted keys, I don't want to run decryption on every key received. Rather put a check to validate if key received is really encrypted and if so, then run decryption and proceed further.

**Sample code snippet:**

```
listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            //Code to decrypt "key"
        }
    };
```

I would like to know, is there a way to put a check to validate if the shared preference key received in callback is encrypted?

P.S. I'm new to android development and question might seem bit naive but Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't determine if some piece of arbitrary data is encrypted using only the data itself. Where does the data come from? You're missing important information in your question...

Comment: I have edited the question with snippet. Here data (key) will come from any shared preference change. Basically any key that is being edited, removed or added in any shared preference.  Let me know if I misunderstood your question about data source. Also, if the keys received were encrypted, that would have been done through "AES" encryption algo.

Comment: You misunderstood.  Where is the potentially encrypted data coming from?

Comment: It's in shared preference files.

Comment: Let me try a different approach.  How are the keys potentially being encrypted?  The encryption algorithm and related options are obviously relevant.

Comment: Key text being stored is first utf-8 encoded and encrypted with "AES".  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, spec);
 cipher.doFinal(keyByteArr);

Comment: Steps : utf-8 encoding using "text.getBytes("UTF-8")"   --> encryption of byte array as mentioned in earlier comment --> byte array to hex string conversion --> Stored in shared preference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any decent, modern encryption algorithm has the property that the ciphertext it produces is indistinguishable from random noise.  This intuitively means that given the ciphertext, and nothing but the ciphertext, we cannot deduce whether the data we have *actually is* a ciphertext or is just arbitrary random bytes or some other encoding that we can't semantically understand.

You could avoid this issue easily by simply including a predictable sequence at the start of any ciphertext that you produce.  You can then check for this sequence when necessary.

I will also note that the encryption code you have is **very** insecure.  It uses ECB mode and is not authenticated.  Under the right circumstances, it will be very easy to retrieve the plaintext.  You need to research best practice symmetric encryption further.

Also, in your comments, you say encode to UTF-8.  You're actually **decoding** from UTF-8.  UTF-8 is a character encoding.